# Import list Sharepoint from Excel

Tags: development

How to import from Excel to Sharepoint without any Font Face.

Now when I'm importing the 1020 elements from Excel to sharepoint it always gives me a this code:

```
<font face="Tahoma" color="#000000">Kate</font>
```

I want only Cate, without a Font Face. How to import plain text? Please help, because i can't find a values in this format. When i delete font face it works, but I dont want always dalete Font Face in 1020 elements, after import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I Managed :) I change a plain Text in column, with no Formating :) And now it's work :)

Comment: But I manage thanks myself answer in this question.